# SQL query not returning correct result using three table together?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in which `tbl_user_signup_info`, `tbl_main_lead_info` and `tbl_campaign_info`, I need a result in which it display info such that each row display the lead id and campaign id added by corresponding registered users of the `tbl_user_signup_info` and display should be like `User_Id, Lead_Id, Campaign_ID`.

Actually i want Total number of leads added by particular user with there Lead Id and Total number of campaign added by that user with there Campaign_Id using those 3 tables.

But i am lacking to form SQL query.

My Result are as below which are wrong:

[image: Result]

Table structure

```
--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_campaign_info`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_campaign_info`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_campaign_info` (
  `Campaign_Id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CampaignName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `CampaignStatus` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `CampaignDescription` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CampaignOwnerNotes` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CampaignAdminNotes` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CampaignStartDate` date NOT NULL,
  `CampaignEndDate` date NOT NULL,
  `CampaignLead_Id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `CampaignAddedBy` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `CampaignAddedOn` date DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `Campaign_Id` (`Campaign_Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_main_lead_info`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_main_lead_info`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_main_lead_info` (
  `Lead_Id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FirstName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Company` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'NA',
  `Website` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'NA',
  `Designation` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'NA',
  `Linkedin` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'NA',
  `Email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TechArea` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirmType` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirmSize` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastContactDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `NextContactDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeadDescription` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OwnerNotes` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SetReminder` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `AdminNotes` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeadStatus` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeadAddedBy` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `LeadAddedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Lead_Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `FirstName` (`FirstName`,`LastName`,`Company`,`Website`,`Designation`,`Linkedin`,`Email`,`Phone`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_main_lead_info`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_main_lead_info` (`Lead_Id`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Company`, `Website`, `Designation`, `Linkedin`, `Email`, `Phone`, `State`, `Country`, `TechArea`, `FirmType`, `FirmSize`, `LastContactDate`, `NextContactDate`, `LeadDescription`, `OwnerNotes`, `SetReminder`, `AdminNotes`, `LeadStatus`, `LeadAddedBy`, `LeadAddedOn`) VALUES
(15, 'John', 'Doe', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'Texas', 'USA', 'test', 'Corporate', '11-50', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10', 'Testing Description of Lead information', NULL, '2020-01-11', 'This need to be confidential by admin', 'Active', 18, '2020-01-09 16:07:17');

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_campaign_info`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_campaign_info` (`Campaign_Id`, `CampaignName`, `CampaignStatus`, `CampaignDescription`, `CampaignOwnerNotes`, `CampaignAdminNotes`, `CampaignStartDate`, `CampaignEndDate`, `CampaignLead_Id`, `CampaignAddedBy`, `CampaignAddedOn`) VALUES
(16, 'Test', 'Active', 'Test', NULL, 'This is admin notes and need to be kept confidential', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10', 15, 18, '2020-01-09'),
(17, 'Test', 'Active', 'Test ', NULL, 'NA', '2020-01-10', '2020-01-10', 15, 18, '2020-01-09');


--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_user_signup_info`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_user_signup_info`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_user_signup_info` (
  `User_Id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserEmail` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `UserPassword` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Admin` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`User_Id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `Email` (`UserEmail`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UserName` (`UserName`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UserEmail` (`UserEmail`,`UserName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_user_signup_info`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_user_signup_info` (`User_Id`, `UserEmail`, `UserName`, `UserPassword`, `Admin`) VALUES
(18, 'test@gmail.com', 'test', 'test', 1),
(22, 'test1@gmail.com', 'test1', 'test1', 0),
(23, 'test2@gmail.com', 'test2', 'test2', 0);
COMMIT;
```

and My SQl Query is as below:

```
SELECT User_Id, Campaign_Id, Lead_Id 
FROM   tbl_campaign_info AS C, 
       tbl_main_lead_info AS M,
       tbl_user_signup_info AS U 
WHERE  C.CampaignAddedBy IN ( SELECT User_Id 
                              FROM   tbl_user_signup_info AS U, 
                                     tbl_campaign_info AS C 
                              WHERE  U.User_Id = C.CampaignAddedBy) 
AND    M.LeadAddedBy IN (SELECT User_Id 
                         FROM   tbl_user_signup_info AS U, 
                                tbl_main_lead_info AS M 
                         WHERE  U.User_Id = M.LeadAddedBy )
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i updated my question

Comment: Please don't use comma-separated joins anymore. They are a relict of the 1980s. Use explicite joins (e.g. `FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.colx = t1.coly`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want users campaign counts and lead counts per user. So, select campaign counts, select lead counts, join them.

You could use a full outer join of the two results for this (thus getting only those users that have at least one campain or lead), but MySQL doesn't support it. I take it that `tbl_user_signup_info` contains one row per user, though, so you can use this as a base table. The following query gives you a result for every user in that table.

```
select
  u.user_id,
  coalesce(c.total, 0) as campaign_count, 
  coalesce(l.total, 0) as lead_count
from tbl_user_signup_info u
left join
(
  select campaignaddedby, count(*) as total
  from tbl_campaign_info
  group by campaignaddedby
) c on c.campaignaddedby = u.user_id
left join
(
  select leadaddedby, count(*) as total
  from tbl_main_lead_info
  group by leadaddedby
) l on l.leadaddedby = u.user_id
order by u.user_id;
```

Comment: That was good displaying 0 for other registered user but can i display user name, user email and admin field value of that user in the table

Comment: Yes. Just add them to the select clause.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can only use `JOIN`.

```
SELECT U.User_Id, Campaign_Id, Lead_Id 
FROM   tbl_user_signup_info AS U 
JOIN  tbl_campaign_info AS C ON U.User_Id = C.CampaignAddedBy
JOIN  tbl_main_lead_info AS M ON U.User_Id = M.LeadAddedBy
```

Comment: can i also get total number of leads and campaigns added by that user, may be it is displayed with corresponding User Id

Comment: Is that your expect ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44aa68/5  If that isn't your expect could you provide some expect result

Comment: yes that Count(*) work but it is returning 2? i think only 1 should be there

Comment: yes the result table formed is correct but i want to use some query to use that table in new query to return unique pairs of (userid, leadid) and (userid, campaignid)

Answer (score 1):

> Actually i want **Total number of leads added by particular user** with
>   there Lead Id and **Total number of campaign added by that user** with
>   there Campaign_Id using those 3 tables.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    X.USER_ID, 
    X.LeadCount, 
    IF(Y.LEAD_ID IS NULL, 0, Y.LEAD_ID) LEAD_ID, 
    IF(Y.CampaignCount IS NULL, 0, Y.CampaignCount) CampaignCount
FROM (
    SELECT 
        U.User_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT LEAD_ID) LeadCount 
    FROM 
        tbl_user_signup_info U
    LEFT JOIN 
        tbl_main_lead_info M
    ON (U.User_Id = M.LeadAddedBy)
    GROUP BY 
        U.USER_ID
) X
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        M.LeadAddedBy, M.LEAD_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT Campaign_Id) CampaignCount 
    FROM 
        tbl_campaign_info C
    LEFT JOIN 
        tbl_main_lead_info M
    ON (C.CampaignAddedBy = M.LeadAddedBy)
    GROUP BY 
        M.LeadAddedBy, M.LEAD_ID
) Y
ON (
    X.USER_ID = Y.LeadAddedBy
)
```

SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e138/40

Comment: Yes that was something i searching thanks but i think i need to display corresponding lead id, campaign id separatly

Comment: what about the corresponding lead id and corresponding campaign id

Comment: My bad, give me a min. :)

Comment: I think i need to separate queries for that

Comment: Yes, we'll have to but I'm trying to club them into one.

Comment: Try now, I have clubbed.

Comment: Also what about other user which are also registered but not added any lead and campaign, there should be zero return in there row.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please try now. I think it should do.